# Jinja include with "ignore misssing" fails with UndefinedError

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Based on the user's permissions, I want to pass in a variable to an admin template to include in a Jinja template. If the variable isn't passed in, the user didn't have permission and I don't want to include anything.

```py
@app.route("/")
def index():
    if user_status == "admin":
        return render_template("index.html", admin_management="admin.html")

    return render_template("index.html", userName=userName)
```

```html
    </li>
    {% include admin_management ignore missing %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

I thought `ignore missing` would tell Jinja to ignore the variable if it wasn't passed, but I get an `UndefinedError`.

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'admin_management' is undefined
```

How do I include a template only if the variable naming it is passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ignore missing` refers to ignoring if the template with the given name is missing, not if the variable that contains the name is missing. Use an `if` block if the variable might not be defined.

```
{% if admin_management is defined %}
  {% include admin_management %}
{% endif %}
```

You probably don't need `ignore missing` in your case, but you can leave it in if the template might be missing too.